# How to add border to galleria big image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, galleria

Hi I want to add a border to galleria big image. How can I give that?

I give like this

```
div.galleria-image img{ border: 5px solid #ccc; }
```

but it cuts right or bottom border and also shows a top border to the thumbail images.

this is my css file.

```
.galleria-container{position:relative;overflow:hidden; height:570px; margin-bottom:30px; }
.galleria-thumbnails-container { }
.galleria-container img{-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;}
.galleria-stage{position:absolute;top:10px;bottom:80px;left:0px;right:10px;overflow:hidden;}
div.galleria-stage img { border: 1px solid red; }
.galleria-thumbnails-container{height:65px;bottom:0;position:absolute;left:0px;right:10px;z-index:2;}
.galleria-carousel .galleria-thumbnails-list{margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px;}
.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image{height:50px;width:60px;background:#fff;margin:0 13px 0 0; float:left;cursor:pointer;}
.galleria-counter{position:absolute;bottom:10px;left:10px;text-align:right;color:#fff;font:normal 11px/1 arial,sans-serif;z-index:2; }
.galleria-loader{background:#000;width:20px;height:20px;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;z-index:2;display:none;background:url(images/classic-loader.gif) no-repeat 2px 2px; }
.galleria-info{width:50%;top:15px;left:15px;z-index:2;position:absolute;}
.galleria-info-text{background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.9);padding: 12px;display:none;}
.galleria-info-title{font:bold 12px/1.1 arial,sans-serif;margin:0;color:#fff;}
.galleria-info-description{font:italic 12px/1.4 georgia,serif;margin:0;color:#bbb; }
.galleria-info-title+.galleria-info-description{margin-top:7px;}
.galleria-info-close{width:9px;height:9px;position:absolute;top:5px;right:5px;background-position:-753px -11px;opacity:.5;cursor:pointer;display:none;}
.galleria-info-link{background-position:-669px -5px;opacity:.8;position:absolute;width:20px;height:20px;cursor:pointer;background-color:#000;}
.galleria-info-link:hover,
.galleria-info-close:hover{opacity:.5; }
.galleria-image-nav{position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-15px;width:100%;height:31px;left:0; }
.galleria-image-nav-left,
.galleria-image-nav-right{opacity:.7;cursor:pointer;width:16px;height:31px;position:absolute;left:10px;z-index:2;}
.galleria-image-nav-right{left:auto;right:10px;background-position:-300px 0;z-index:2;}
.galleria-image-nav-left:hover,
.galleria-image-nav-right:hover{opacity:1.0;}
.galleria-thumb-nav-left,
.galleria-thumb-nav-right{cursor:pointer;display:none;background-position:-495px 11px;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;height:60px;width:23px;z-index:3;opacity:1.0;}
.galleria-thumb-nav-right{background-position:-578px 11px;border-right:none;right:0;left:auto;}
.galleria-thumbnails-container .disabled,
.galleria-thumbnails-container .disabled:hover{opacity:.6;cursor:default; }
.galleria-thumb-nav-left:hover,
.galleria-thumb-nav-right:hover{opacity:1;/*background-color:#111;*/}
.galleria-carousel .galleria-thumb-nav-left,
.galleria-carousel .galleria-thumb-nav-right{display:block; }
.galleria-thumb-nav-left,
.galleria-thumb-nav-right,
.galleria-info-link,
.galleria-info-close,
.galleria-image-nav-left,
.galleria-image-nav-right{background-image:url(images/classic-map.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
div.galleria-image img{ border: 5px solid #ccc; }
```

any body knows the solution please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call galleria(), set the image_margin option to 2 (note: when I tried 1, the bottom margin was chopped). This is what I use:

```
$('#gallery').galleria({
    autoplay: 5000,
    data_source: slides,
    pause_on_interaction: false,
    transition: 'fade',
    image_margin: 2
});
```

My site's css file has the following definition to add a 1px gray border to the large image:

.galleria-stage img {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `border: 1px solid red;` to `div.galleria-image img`

> div.galleria-image img{ border: 1px
>   solid red; }

Edit: Seems like CSS above will results in the thumbnails having borders too.

Try this:

> div.galleria-stage img { border: 1px solid red; }

Comment: Hello sir If give like that it create a top border on galleria thumbnail design.

Comment: ok sir but that main image right border is not showing. what to do for that?

Comment: div.galleria-stage img { border: 1px solid red; } this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the overflow of the parent div's i had this problem and i added and it worked great

`.galleria-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.galleria-image, .galleria-stage {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.galleria-stage .galleria-images .galleria-image img {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the imageMargin option needs to be set to twice what it should be.

http://galleria.io/docs/options/imageMargin/

Like I've been trying to put a 6px border around it, and the bottom kept getting cut off, until I set imageMargin to 12.

Answer (score 0):

If your border is for example 4 px then you should set the image_margin variable to 8, if the border is 8px then set it to 16 (the double since you have two sides).

```
$('#gallery').galleria({
    image_margin: 8
});
```